# How can I get reports from Google Cloud Storage using the Google's API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, google-api-python-client

I have to create a program that get informations on a daily basis about installations of a group of apps on the AppStore and the PlayStore.

For the PlayStore, using Google Cloud Storage I followed the instructions on this page using the client library and a Service Account method and the Python code example :
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en&ref_topic=7071935

I slightly changed the given code to make it work since documentation looks not up-to-date. I made it possible to connect to the API and it seems to connect correctly.

My problem is that I don't understand what object I get and how to use it. It's not a report it just looks like files properties in a dict.

This is my code (private data "hidden") :

```
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

client_email = '************.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
json_file = 'PATH/TO/MY/JSON/FILE'
cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_**********'
report_to_download = 'stats/installs/installs_****************_202005_app_version.csv'
private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file, scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')

storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

supposed_to_be_report = storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket, object=report_to_download).execute()
```

When I print the *supposed_to_be_report* - which is a dictionary-  I only get what I understand as Metadata about he report like this:

```
{'kind': 'storage#object', 'id': 'pubsite_prod_rev_***********/stats/installs/installs_****************_202005_app_version.csv/1591077412052716', 
'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_***********/o/stats%2Finstalls%2Finstalls_*************_202005_app_version.csv', 
'mediaLink': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_***********/o/stats%2Finstalls%2Finstalls_****************_202005_app_version.csv?generation=1591077412052716&alt=media', 
'name': 'stats/installs/installs_***********_202005_app_version.csv', 
'bucket': 'pubsite_prod_rev_***********', 
'generation': '1591077412052716', 
'metageneration': '1', 
'contentType': 'text/csv; 
charset=utf-16le', 'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 'size': '378', 'md5Hash': '*****==', 'contentEncoding': 'gzip'......
```

I am not sure I'm using it correctly. Could you please explain me where am I wrong and/or how to get installs reports correctly ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using `googleapiclient.discovery` client, this is not an issue, but the recommended way to access Google Cloud APIs programmatically is by using the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_cloud_client_libraries).

Second, you are just retrieving the object's metadata. You can download the object to have access to the file contents, this is a sample using the client library.

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

Sample taken from [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python).