# Download Play Console Report Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, google-cloud-storage, google-play-console

I am currently trying to export my report in play console using automation script in python. I already following some of this documentation https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en.

My code ends up like this:

```
cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
report_to_download = 'reviews/reviews_id.co.sample.sample_202012.csv'

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(json_file)

storage = build('storage', 'v1',  credentials=credentials)

print(storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket,object=report_to_download).execute())
```

and i got this output:

```
{'kind': 'storage#object', 
'id':'pubsite_prod_rev_16380265360184632708/reviews/reviews_id.co.acehardware.acerewards_202012.csv/1638300444416618', 
'selfLink':'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXX/o/reviews%2Freviews_id.co.acehardware.acerewards_202012.csv', 
'mediaLink':'https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_16380265360184632708/o/reviews%2Freviews_id.co.sample.sample.csv?generation=1638300444416618&alt=media', 
'name': 'reviews/reviews_id.co.sample.sample_202012.csv', 
'bucket': 'pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
'generation': '1638300444416618', 
'metageneration': '1', 
'contentType': 'text/csv; charset=utf-16le', 
'storageClass': 'STANDARD', 
'size': '18842', 
'md5Hash': 'ywjrTfTj/TjFuVkeawlNj/fQ==', 
'contentEncoding': 'gzip', 
'crc32c': 'wpasdROSg==', 
'etag': 'COq0sadoeDowPQCEAE=', 
'timeCreated': '2021-11-30T19:27:24.488Z', 
'updated': '2021-11-30T19:27:24.488Z', 
'timeStorageClassUpdated': '2021-11-30T19:27:24.488Z'}
```

how can i create some csv output object to my local storage or saved to StringIO buffer with this output?

Comment: Have you checked this [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152795/how-can-i-get-reports-from-google-cloud-storage-using-the-googles-api?rq=1)?

Comment: You can do it following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238826)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) which provides sample Python code to download objects to your local storage.

The code snippet you are interested in is:

> blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, particularly for downloading Google Play Console reports, it is better to use `gsutil` (although more Python way would be not to call some external process, but using API). This will suit your needs better because it will download reports to your local storage all at once.

Also, and more important, people report [a lot of problem cases with 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734148/how-to-fix-permission-denied-when-trying-to-download-google-play-app-reports) for accessing these types of reports `pubsite_prod_rev_X_***` - they are not listed in your GCS buckets and you can't change a permissions properly to access them which is required for API. But I found `gsutil` working in this case. Here is a code sample:

```py
    import os
    import pathlib
    import subprocess
    import shutil

    gsutil_path = shutil.which('gsutil')
    if not gsutil_path:
        # if gsutil isn't in PATH
        gsutil_path = shutil.which('gsutil',path=os.getenv('GSUTIL_PATH'))
    print(str(subprocess.check_output([
        gsutil_path,
        'cp',
        '-r',
        os.getenv('GOOGLE_STORAGE_REPORTS_URI'),
        pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()])))
```